# How to set web-gui firewall to block everything for MAC except port XX

Tags: firewall, openwrt

I'm trying to block all access except for the web for one of the connected PCs and while blocking all works fine, adding exception rules for web traffic doesn't work.

[image: rules]

I've tried moving them above and under "Filter-Parental-Control" without any luck.

EDIT: And they were checked, had to uncheck to post here.

Answer (score 1):

The source port of a TCP connection is random, not the same as the target port. So, your "from port 80" rule is overrestrictive.

Comment: Ah, right, that didn't make it work though.